# In mongodb sharded collection how to update the shard key values

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-update

I am using mongo 4.2 version. I have created a sharded collection. I want to update the values of few fields which include sharded keys. As per the mongo document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#change-a-document-s-shard-key-value .It says that we can update the value of shard keys. But I am getting the following error

```
Performing an update on the path 'status' would modify the immutable field 'status'
```

Please let me know what am I missing here

I tried the below query

```
.updateOne({date:{'$gte': '2021-01-01', '$lte': '2021-01-15'}, 
status: 'U' ,
type: 'SC',
name: 'product1',
currency: 'INR' },
{$set: {status: 'M'}})
```

This is the shard keys

```
 shard key: {
                        "date" : 1,
                        "status" : 1,
                        "type" : 1,
                        "name" : 1,
                        "currency" : 1
                        }
```

Comment: What is your shard key (compound key?) and how does your update look like?

Comment: Did you try `updateMany()` (or `multi: true`)? You can update only single documents, i.e. `updateOne()`

Comment: Also post a sample input document, and tell what your shard key is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ensure you are not running the database in feature compatibility mode with a previous version `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.2" } )`. Shard keys were immutable before v4.2.

Then ensure there are no documents where "status" is part of the compound primary key _id:
`.find( { "_id.status": {$exists: true} } )`. _id is still immutable regardless of sharding and it's one of the reasons to use ObjectID for primary keys.